# Media3 ExoPlayer PlayerView UI - seekbar doesn't work (to change position) and rewind/fast forward buttons are disabled

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-media3

I'm trying to play `.m4a` audio file (DocumentProvider/SAF URI, e.g: `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AVoiceRecorder/document/primary%3AVoiceRecorder%2F2024-02-09%2017h%2016m%2040s.m4a`) but I can't change position using seekbar and rewind/fast forward buttons are disabled for some reason. Why?

```
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
player.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri(audioFileUri))
player.playWhenReady = true
player.prepare()
```

ui:

```
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
    factory = {
        // androidx.media3.ui.PlayerView
        PlayerView(it).also { playerView ->
            playerView.controllerHideOnTouch = false
            playerView.controllerAutoShow = true
            playerView.controllerShowTimeoutMs = 0
            playerView.player = player
            playerView.setShowRewindButton(true)
            playerView.setShowFastForwardButton(true)
            playerView.showController()
        }
    },
)
```

[image]

```
val media3Version = "1.2.1"
implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:$media3Version")
implementation("androidx.media3:media3-session:$media3Version")
implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:$media3Version")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using [setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media3/extractor/DefaultExtractorsFactory#setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled(boolean)):

```
val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(context)
    .setMediaSourceFactory(
        DefaultMediaSourceFactory(
            /* context = */ context,
            /* extractorsFactory = */ DefaultExtractorsFactory().apply {
                setConstantBitrateSeekingEnabled(true)
            }
        )
    )
    .build()
```